# Minecraft says I have out of date drivers. Cannot find any drivers for it though

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I have a ATI/AMD HD Radeon 4200. As the title says, I can't find any drivers. Could someone please help find the latest drivers? I am running Windows 8.1

Comment: Have you got the latest version of Java? Download it from https://java.com/download.

Comment: I am on the drivers website. Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197982/minecraft-1-8-graphics-driver-crash-windows-8, which is also complaining of Minecraft crashing with the same error message on a computer with the same graphics card

Answer (score 2):

Well, here are the latest drivers for your Graphics Card.

---

## ATI/AMD HD Radeon 4200

### 32-Bit - Windows 8

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2032

### 64-Bit - Windows 8

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064

If these weren't the drivers you were looking for, you can do a manual or automatic search on the website [**here**](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

---

Also check to make sure you have the latest version of Java.

You can download the latest version from the website [**here**](http://java.com/download).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a laptop, there is a high chance that the only way you are able to (easily) install new drivers is if your laptop manufacturer releases them, which doesn't usually happen. With a desktop, or to see if your laptop can use the official drivers, go to your manufacturers website and find the button related to drivers, the other answer has links for you.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download is the link for downloading the auto-detect tool, or manually searching for drivers.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2032 is the link for 32 bit windows 8.1.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064 is the link for 64 bit windows 8.1.

Comment: **zachary** has stated their Graphics Card. Maybe it would be useful to add the links into yours? What if I delete my answer? You can use the links, I don't own them.